# Why is my vlookup value filling to rows rather than columns?

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, google-sheets-formula

I'm using `VLOOKUP` to get values from another sheet. However, the result is unexpected. The values are filled to row, not column. I'd like these values to fill into columns instead. How can I achieve this?

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(A4;'Stok Gudang Bangka'!A4:E12;{2;3;4};0))
```

[image: Image showing the issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your formula in [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262).